# Display card background image from local for the list of item from API

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Good Day! I am trying to keep the background image for the items that I am fetching from the API. No image is coming from API for the background. In this case, I want to add the background image from my local system based on the item ID. Item ID is one of the unique value I am getting from the API. As of now below code is working for me. Anyone can help me to achieve this in a better way. Thanks in advance.

```
<FlatList
                numColumns={numColumns}
                data={data, numColumns}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
                
                  return (
                    <Card
                      style={{
                        margin: 8,
                        borderRadius: 16,
                        width: config.deviceWidth * 0.43,
                        height: config.deviceWidth * 0.54,
                        overflow: "hidden",
                        justifyContent: "space-evenly",
                        marginLeft: 14,
                      }}
                    >
                      <ImageBackground
                        style={{
                          height: config.deviceWidth * 0.54,
                          width: config.deviceWidth * 0.43,
                        }}
                        source={
                          item.itemID === "1"
                            ? require("../../../public/myimages/itemID1.png")
                            : item.itemID === "2"
                            ? require("../../../public/myimages/itemID2.png")
                            : item.itemID === "3"
                            ? require("../../../public/myimages/itemID3.jpg")
                            : item.itemID === "4"
                            ? require("../../../public/myimages/itemID4.jpg")
                            : item.itemID === "5"
                            ? require("../../../public/myimages/itemID5.jpg")
                            : item.itemID === "6"
                            ? require("../../../public/myimages/itemID6.jpg")
                            : item.itemID === "7"
                            ? require("../../../public/myimages/itemID7.jpg")
                            : item.itemID === "8"
                            ? require("../../../public/myimages/itemID8.jpg")
                            : item.itemID === "9"
                            ? require("../../../public/myimages/itemID9.jpg")
                            : item.itemID === "10"
                            ? require("../../../public/myimages/itemID10.png")
                            : require("../../../public/myimages/img3.jpg")
                        }
                   
                      >
                      </Card>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this line,

```
                  source={
                          item.itemID === "1"
                            ? require("../../../public/myimages/itemID1.png")
                            : item.itemID === "2"
                            ? require("../../../public/myimages/itemID2.png")
                            : item.itemID === "3"
                            ? require("../../../public/myimages/itemID3.jpg")
                            : item.itemID === "4"
                            ? require("../../../public/myimages/itemID4.jpg")
                            : item.itemID === "5"
                            ? require("../../../public/myimages/itemID5.jpg")
                            : item.itemID === "6"
                            ? require("../../../public/myimages/itemID6.jpg")
                            : item.itemID === "7"
                            ? require("../../../public/myimages/itemID7.jpg")
                            : item.itemID === "8"
                            ? require("../../../public/myimages/itemID8.jpg")
                            : item.itemID === "9"
                            ? require("../../../public/myimages/itemID9.jpg")
                            : item.itemID === "10"
                            ? require("../../../public/myimages/itemID10.png")
                            : require("../../../public/myimages/img3.jpg")
                        }
```

why can't you use a **switch** statement?

```
const getImageName = (itemId) => {
        switch (itemId) {
            case "1":
                return 'itemID1.png';

            case "2":
                return 'itemID2.png';

            case "3":
                return 'itemID3.jpg';

                .............
                
            default:
                return 'img3.jpg';
        }
    }

  
    

     <ImageBackground style={{height: config.deviceWidth * 0.54, 
                            width: config.deviceWidth * 0.43}}  
    source={require("../../../public/myimages/"+ getImageName(item.itemID))} />
```

Comment: While I am doing this I am getting the error like "Invalid call". And I see that since we are using  the static images we want to use require in switch case itself. Even I used  require in switch I am facing the same error "Invalid call"